# Unix character set conversion

Tags: character-encoding

I'm confused by character-sets in Unix. I have a CSV file downloaded via SFTP:

```
$ file -ib myfile
text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

The purpose for this character-set quest is that the data within file is seen like:

```
Flyers:Â VideoÂ Center
```

While I want:

```
Flyers: Video Center
```

I tried:

```
iconv -f us-ascii -t utf-8 myfile
```

Which is throwing the following error:

```
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 528666
```

Please clarify what's going on regarding character-sets? Can I download in UTF-8 while getting a file via SFTP?  How do we usually decide on what is junk within a character set?

```
$Locale  
LANG=en_US.UTF-8  
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

---

```
$  LC_ALL=C sed -n l  
Zimbabwe,175,Unknown Network,-1,Unknown,-1,Unknown,-1,US: Flyers:Â VideoÂ Center:,854088,Standard Display,-998,10/28/2014
```

---

```
$ iconv -f utf-8 -t l1   
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 1228354
```

When set Terminal (Under Transalation, character set to UTF-8), I am able to see clean data.
But, when I read this with UTF-8 encoding using a ETL tool; the data is read as junk.

When I grep my file for data

```
"Flyers: Video Center"
```

I don't see result for the fact that data is stored as

```
"Flyers:Â VideoÂ Center"
```

Can the file coding be changed so as to see what I want?

hexdump for junk characters:

```
0000000: 4e42 4353 3a20 4e48 4c2e 636f 6d3a 2055  NBCS: NHL.com: U  
0000010: 533a 2046 6c79 6572 733a c2a0 5669 6465  S: Flyers:..Vide  
0000020: 6fc2 a043 656e 7465 723a 2057 6861 7427  o..Center: What'  
0000030: 7320 486f 740a                           s Hot.  


$dd bs=1 skip=1228300 count=100 < temp1.csv | xxd  
100+0 records in  
100+0 records out  
100 bytes (100 B) copied, 0.000141 seconds, 709 kB/s  
0000000: 3031 342c 320a 556e 6b6e 6f77 6e20 436f  014,2.Unknown Co  
0000010: 756e 7472 792c 2d31 2c48 756c 7520 4c69  untry,-1,Hulu Li  
0000020: 7665 2c33 3738 3834 312c 4e42 433a 2041  ve,378841,NBC: A  
0000030: 6d65 7269 6361 e280 9973 2047 6f74 2054  merica...s Got T  
0000040: 616c 656e 743a 2053 686f 7274 666f 726d  alent: Shortform    
0000050: 2c33 3230 3631 3332 2c55 6e6b 6e6f 776e  ,3206132,Unknown  
0000060: 2053 6974                                 Sit
```

Some garbled text:

```
Junk Americaâs
```

must have been   (Note that apostrophe is not this ' but ’)

```
America’s
```

And

```
BMW â Golden
```

must have been  (Note that hyphen is long hyphen not this -):

```
BMW – Golden
```

Comment: Can you paste a hexdump of the relevant parts somewhere, please (`xxd TheFile.csv | head`)? Guessing the correct encoding from your question is difficult. It is definitely not `us-ascii`, it could be for example `latin1`.

Comment: 0000000: 7265 706f 7274 206e 616d 653a 2048 6973  report name: His
0000010: 746f 7269 6361 6c5f 436f 6e73 7472 6169  torical_Constrai
0000020: 6e65 645f 4176 6169 6c73 0a64 6174 6520  ned_Avails.date
0000030: 7261 6e67 653a 2032 3031 342d 3130 2d32  range: 2014-10-2

Comment: 0000040: 3865 6474 2d32 3031 342d 3130 2d32 3865  8edt-2014-10-28e
0000050: 6474 0a43 6f75 6e74 7279 2c4d 524d 2043  dt.Country,MRM C
0000060: 6f75 6e74 7279 2049 442c 4469 7374 7269  ountry ID,Distri
0000070: 6275 746f 722c 4d52 4d20 4469 7374 7269  butor,MRM Distri
0000080: 6275 746f 7220 4944 2c53 6572 6965 732c  butor ID,Series,
0000090: 4d52 4d20 5365 7269 6573 2049 442c 5369  MRM Series ID,Si

Comment: Why does my file -ib command says us-ascii then? Also how do i find the characters in a file that are not supported by UTF-8 assuming file is in UTF-8 or any other character encoding

Comment: Please edit your question to add the portion of the output of `LC_ALL=C sed -n l` on your file that covers that Â character. `file` uses simple heuristics to determine a charset, you can't trust it for that.

Comment: Also, please include the output of `locale` in your question. My bet would be that the file is in UTF-8 already (and that's a non-breaking-space character (encoded as 0xc2 0xa0) but your locale is not (for instance it may be iso8859-1 where 0xc2 is Â and 0xa0 is nbsp).

Comment: sorry Stephane, what does "output of LC_ALL=C sed -n l on your file" mean?

Comment: @Abhishek - please move this new information into your question. Do not merely add the output as comments. It's difficult to decipher what you're showing in the above.

Comment: @Abhishek - he's asking you to run this command: `LC_ALL=C sed -n l somefile` and post the results as an edit to your question.

Comment: Please add that to your question (click on [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/171226/edit)). If you see that Â in a terminal, then it could be that your terminal is not in UTF-8 despite your locale, or it could be that the file has undergone a iso-8859-1 -> utf-8 conversion twice (we could confirm if you run `LC_ALL=C sed -n l < file.csv`. Either way, a `iconv -f utf-8 -t l1` would probably fix it (for your terminal at least).

Comment: @slm - Thanks for the learnings. I am new to forum & happy to see quick response.

Comment: @Abhishek - yup. Help everyone here to help you 8-).

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas - Thanks for explanation & patience.

Comment: BTW, my question is still open & have added further details by editing my post

Comment: Thanks for the hexdump. The beginning of the file really seems to be us-ascii (7bit).  Can you post a hexdump of the *relevant* lines (where the strange characters appear)?

Comment: What system is that? Was it `LC_ALL=C sed -n l your-file` you really ran? Having a non-ASCII character in the output  of that would be a `sed` bug. We still don't know what byte sequence those Â are really made of. And it sounds possible you have both UTF-8 and non-UTF-8 character. Does position 1228354 correspond to those Â or something else?

Comment: Your hexdump confirms that's a UTF-8 encoded non-breaking-space character. Now since `iconv -f utf-8` complains, there are some other byte sequences elsewhere in the file that don't form valid UTF-8 characters. What's the output of `dd bs=1 skip=1228300 count=100 < file.csv | hd`? (or `xxd` if you don't have `hd`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - "NBC: Americaâs" is the junk at 1228354

Comment: 에이바 - Isn't working

Comment: iconv -f CP1252 -t UTF-8 myfile | dos2unix > myoutfile

Comment: That's a valid UTF-8 character. The `iconv -f utf-8 -t l1` didn't work because that character doesn't exist in l1 (aka latin1 aka iso-8859-1). So your file seems to be valid UTF-8. The problem (if any) probably is with your ETL tool. If it expects iso8859-1 encoding, you can try and get an approximation with `iconv -f utf-8 -t l1//TRANSLIT`

Answer (score 1):

**Issue #1: grepping "Flyers: Video Center"... I don't see the result** :

In the hexadecimal dump of the file, notice the two bytes C2A0 between the words *Flyers:* and *Video*. This is a the UTF8 encoding for [Non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space). **[grepping NBSP is known to fail](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/tree/tests/multibyte-white-space)** For more information, read [How to remove special 'M-BM-' character with sed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/357248/how-to-remove-special-m-bm-character-with-sed) and [use sed to replace ...Hex c2a0](https://superuser.com/questions/517847/use-sed-to-replace-nbsp-160-hex-00a0-octal-240-non-breaking-space). Short answer is:

```
sed -i.bak -e 's/\xc2\xa0/ /' /path/to/file
```

**Issue #2 `America’s' shows as 'Americaâs' (??)**:

Here, the dump contains three bytes e28099, known as [RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK](http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8192&number=128) (’). Actually, there should be no problem here ! You probably got distracted by the problem above (could you confirm?)

If you use `grep`, `sed` and other tools with expression that respect your locale (UTF8!), then it will work:

```
printf 'America\xe2\x80\x99s\n' | grep --only-matching "[[:punct:]]"
printf 'America\xe2\x80\x99s\n' | sed -e "s/[[:punct:]]/?/"
```

If you want to get rid of all those UTF-8 "*special*" characters, use can use the tips above or `iconv` (but nowadays, there are few excuses not to support UTF8).

Drop all non-ascii chars:

```
type a.txt | iconv -f utf8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT
```

Or to preserve chars from one locale:

```
type a.txt | iconv -f utf8 -t iso8859-15//TRANSLIT | iconv -f iso8859-15 -t utf8
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike **XML**, which should contain an encoding tag that describes the original content encoding you have to get that piece of information for csv with other means.

While **type** works pretty well on binary data, it does not work well on text data.

This is due to the way the command works. see **man text**. Roughly: It looks at the first couple of bytes and tries to guess the content looking up what was found in a lookup-table.

So usually it is best practice to ask the originator of the content which charset was used.

If that is not possible - for whatever reason, **iconv** is your best friend here.